# Game theory statistics problem

Tags: probability, game-theory

I am trying to quantify the win probability of a game where two players have equal skill but one gets more attempts to achieve the best result.  Can someone help me define a mathematical formula to solve a problem like this for example:

Two dart players have equal skill.
Player 1 gets 100 attempts to get closest to the bullseye.
Player 2 gets only 1 attempt.
What is the probability that player 2 wins?

For the sake of simplicity we will assume that darts are marked and removed after each throw, so there is no chance darts interfere with each other, and that no other outside forces impact the results.  We will also assume that there is an infinite level of exactness to the measurement of who is closest, so there will be no ties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Since the two players have equal skill, their collective 101 attempts can be lumped together into a single pool. You're then asking the probability that a particular distinguished one of those attempts (the one corresponding to Player 2) is the best one.

Can you see where to go from here?

Comment: @Théophile Oops! Yes, and fixed -- thanks for the correction.

Comment: I guess where I get confused is whether or not the number of attempts directly effects the probability. I was thinking maybe it was 1/2 ^ 100, as each of player 1's attempts has a 50/50 shot of beating player 2's. But it seems you're suggesting it is simply 1/101?

Comment: Yep! It's just $1/101$. And you can see how the number of attempts *does* indeed affect this; if Player 1 had just $20$ attempts, then the probability of victory for Player 2 would be $1/21$ instead. If Player 2 also has multiple attempts, then it's a slightly more complicated counting problem (but it's not bad).

Comment: The issue with your proposed expression is that you're implicitly assuming independence where you can't; indeed, if Player 1's first shot is worse than Player 2's shot, then this suggests Player 2's shot might have been good, which should imply something about the ensuing probabilities of Player 1's remaining shots beating it.